# Override Exception handling- Oracle ADF

Tags: java, exception, oracle-adf

Does anyone have a example of overriding exception handler done in Oracle ADF?

There is a bug in af:showPrintablePageBehavior that throws a

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ADF_FACES-60003

I the error isn't fatal and because it's a framework error, there isn't a lot I can do except ignoring the exception.

I have seen several similar suggestions on various forums but non of them have a example of a overridden exception handler.

Thanks

Comment: Which JDev version do you use? Do you use Task flows? Have you look into the doc http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26098_01/web.1112/e16182/taskflows_complex.htm#ADFFD22606?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/extending_the_adf_controller_exception_handler In the if-condition you check throwable for the ADF Faces error code

Btw, *"There is a bug in af:showPrintablePageBehavior"*

Do you have a bug number for me? Have you filed the bug, or is it filed by someone else? Which version of JDeveloper has this been filed for?

Comment: Here is a blog, showing to the same problem that I'm having: http://andrejusb.blogspot.com/2012/07/issue-with-show-printable-page-behavior.html
I'm running JDev 11.1.1.5.0
I don't know if the bug has been filled, but I think I have seen it being mentioned somewhere. I'll search for it.

Comment: "Frank Nimphius said...
I filed a bug and provided Andrejus sample as a test case. As said, hope alone doesn't fix problems ;-)" 
A comment on the andrejusb.blogspot.com link that I provided.. Maybe you know the bug number :)

Comment: Bug number is 14341044. However, this issue is filed against 11.1.2.2 (11g R2) and not 11.1.1.1.x (11g R1)

Comment: I'll submit the bug then :)
But back to topic. Whats a good way to treat this bug? I have created a page that doesn't contain any iterators, and the printable text is shown in a af:richTextEditor that takes it's value from a pageFlowScope bean.

Comment: I still have a problem some times, when closing a expanded showDetailItem, that sits outside the region I'm working from.
This happens only after I have clicked the showPrintablePageBehavior